# A doubt in proof of existence of Auslander Reiten Sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, quiver, representation-of-algebras

I am providing the context. You can skip to the actual doubt below. My doubt doesnt need knowledge of quivers or even almost split sequences.

I am reading **Theorem 5.4.10** from the book *An introduction to Quiver Representations* by Derksen.

The claim is the existence of almost split sequence 'ending' at $V$ for any non-projective $A$ module where $A$ is a finite dimensional $\mathbb{C}$ algebra and $V$ is a finite module over $A$.

Formally:

**Theorem 5.4.10**

1. If $N$ is an indecomposable finite dimensional $A$-module which is not projective, then there exists an [almost split sequence](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Almost-split_sequence)

$0 \to L \xrightarrow{f} M \xrightarrow{g} N \to 0$

The **Proof** begins with :  'Let M_1, \cdots M_r' be all the indecomposable modules for which there exists an irreducible morphism $M_i \to N$.

My **doubt** is how can we assume that there are only finitely many such modules upto isomorphism? There is no mention of $A$ being of finite type and I know for a fact that such sequences exist for  any finite type algebra $A$.

Please help me.

Comment: If you want to compare with other proofs, similar results are given in Assem-Simson-Skowronski's Elements of Representation Theory, Volume I, Theorem IV.3.1 and Auslander-Reiten-Smalø's Representation Theory of Artin Algebras Theorem V.1.15.

Comment: @mars412 Yes I have now figured it out. In Derksen, it is being implicitly assumed that the algebra is finite representation type to give this simpler proof from properties of maps involved in A-R sequences